# Multiple Attributes of same name - JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb

Is it possible to have XMLAttributes that have the same name. I have annotated a list property as XMLAttribute(name="default") but it returns as

<  test default="ABC CDF BHY">
 but i was expecting it to return as 
<  test default="ABC" default="CDF" default="BHY">

Is it even possible to do that?

Comment: I think it's a good April 1st one.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't. Not because of some JAXB shortcoming but XML attributes cannot have multiple values by definition.  And XML is very strict regarding its rules.

The best workaround is to redefine the attribute as element. Otherwise when you need to read the attribute, you'll need to parse it and break the value to multiple tokens but I wouldn't recommend this as it is awkward and brittle.

Comment: `XML attributes cannot have multiple values by definition`. Did you mean something else?

Comment: "Attributes with multiple values" means to have the same attribute repeated with the same name but different value as : default="ABC" default="CDF" default="BHY" i.e what the OP wants to achieve. What gets is just a single space delimited value that can be parsed into tokens